# Drops ascii colors using c++

Tags: c++, qt, colors, ascii

I pick text from bash and represent it in a `QPlainTextEdit`. The problem is that the code contains ascii colors ([01;31m) and these are printed in QT like characters, which is very ugly. How can I eliminate this colors or represent in the right way.

Sorry for my bad English.

Output example in `QPlainTextEdit`:

```
[0m[01m[K/home/aron/main.cpp:[m[K In function ‘[01m[Kint main()[m[K’:
```

SOLUTION:

> std::string result = boost::regex_replace(text,
>   boost::regex(R"(\x1B[([\d;])*(m|K))"), "");

Comment: looks someone has already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500429/qtextedit-and-colored-bash-like-output-emulation

Comment: Have the solution usign this lik:  'std::string result = boost::regex_replace(text, boost::regex(R"(\x1B[([\d;])*(m|K))"), "");