# Print ANSI escape codes in QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit, ansi-escape

I'm trying to print debug messages in QTextEdit widget. It's printing fine, but it doesn't decode some of the ANSI escape codes.

For example, to print a warning message, you can do this:

```
print("\033[43mWARNING MESSAGE\033[0m")
```

[image]

And I'm trying to do the same with QTextEdit:

```
textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
textEdit.append(u'\033[43mWARNING MESSAGE\033[0m')
```

but it doesn't work. The output is:

[image]

So do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried : toto = unicode("\033[43mWARNING MESSAGE\033[0m") and then textEdit.append(toto)

Comment: I think it's the same as textEdit.append(u"\033[43mWARNING MESSAGE\033[0m") and it doesn't work. I'm using python 3.5 and pyqt5 and there's no uncode() function

Comment: Those codes aren't "Unicode". They are ANSI codes and depend on the shell you are running.  They certainly aren't portable into generic text display systems and I don't think they'll even work in Windows.

Comment: I think you should be able to easily translate from the techniques used in the duplicate I've just pointed out.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setCurrentCharFormat

Comment: Incidentally it turns out Windows *does* support ANSI codes at last, but only from Windows 10 TH2!!

Comment: @strubbly thanks for explanation and yes it windows 10. Yes textEdit.setHtml is printing with colours but my problem is a bit different, because I'm trying to duplicate print() output into textEdit.

Comment: Ok then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500429/qtextedit-and-colored-bash-like-output-emulation) is the exact duplicate of what you want.  No text formatting in QT will read ANSI codes - you'll need to write your own.