# QML TextArea not able to use HTML style mark up

Tags: qt, qml, textarea

QML TextArea not able to format text using HTML style mark up. Is there anything else I can use?
I am using TextArea, because I want scroll bars as well.

```
    TextArea {
    id: textArea
    font.family: "Times New Roman"
    font.pointSize: 13
    width: parent.width-filters.width;
    height: parent.height- buttons.height
    wrapMode: Text.NoWrap
    readOnly: true
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.top: buttons.bottom
    text: "<b>Lorem</b> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ultricies elit ut commodo cursus. Phasellus pretium, eros sed facilisis pretium, velit nisl tincidunt velit, ut pellentesque est nunc sit amet mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur varius non leo sit amet sagittis. Proin in pharetra enim. Donec commodo mattis est id congue. Duis maximus, nibh vel sagittis dictum, orci dolor lacinia dolor, id pharetra erat odio eget enim. Nulla facilisi. Integer placerat nibh quis interdum rhoncus. Vivamus vel tellus lectus. Suspendisse ut turpis nec mi finibus auctor. Nunc accumsan ligula vulputate mi rhoncus, vel rhoncus elit suscipit.Aliquam nunc dui, rhoncus et tortor a, tincidunt egestas felis. Vestibulum eget elit ac quam ultrices tincidunt. Ut dignissim eget dui a tempus. Mauris eu porta metus. In at turpis placerat, rutrum libero et, vulputate erat. Integer pellentesque felis ipsum, quis aliquet dolor ultrices a. Curabitur bibendum ultrices justo sed blandit. Vestibulum posuere semper libero et gravida. Quisque placerat tempor enim sit amet placerat. Nullam tempus molestie dictum. Sed vulputate condimentum tellus, eu pretium lorem efficitur sed. Proin quis enim mauris.Proin ultricies sapien eu ligula varius bibendum. Cras ornare pharetra urna vitae maximus. Mauris mollis orci augue, at fringilla ex consequat eu. Sed tristique semper eros, ut luctus justo imperdiet quis. Donec fermentum rhoncus risus id luctus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In iaculis ipsum sit amet sem mollis scelerisque. Phasellus vitae turpis quis tellus egestas venenatis. Sed eget dictum mauris. Sed in nunc aliquam, finibus odio ut, aliquam dolor.Sed pellentesque feugiat mi in interdum. Integer a nibh libero. Donec lacinia velit at blandit semper. Proin in pellentesque turpis. Phasellus et placerat metus. Ut ut porta mauris. Sed vulputate molestie urna, non congue neque gravida quis. Nulla tristique massa a dui tincidunt porta. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus tincidunt augue ut lacus fermentum sollicitudin. Cras consectetur sapien eu est aliquam, sed venenatis purus facilisis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In ac nibh at libero tempor porttitor vel ac tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque et elementum neque.}
```

Is there any way to use terminal escape sequences as well? https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [`textFormat`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textarea.html#textFormat-prop) property:

```
textFormat: Text.RichText
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to use terminal escape sequences as well? https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to do it in QML but you can probably do it manually (maybe have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26524823/4503757)).